# Foreach array with Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, foreach

It seems my code cannot iterate over an array stored in a hash.

What did I miss ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = {array   => ['a', 'b', 'c']};

my @array = $data->{array};
print Dumper(@array); # It looks like $data->{array} is an array

print "Ref: ".ref($data->{array})."\n"; # And this array is indeed an array

foreach ($data->{array}) { print "$_\n"; } # But this doesn't work        
foreach (@array) { print "$_\n"; } # Neither this one

# But with a regular array it works...
my @myNames = ('Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe');
foreach (@myNames) { print "$_\n"; }
```

My output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c'
        ];
$VAR1 = 'a';
Ref: ARRAY
ARRAY(0x8002bcf8)
ARRAY(0x8002bcf8)
Larry
Curly
Moe
```

I am pretty confused with REF/SCALAR types. Sometime Perl takes values as references sometime not. In this case, because I get 'ARRAY' from the `ref` function, I guess `$->{array}` doesn't give me an array but a reference to the array.

I have also tried `@$data->{array}` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data->{array}` is indeed an array reference.

To dereference it, use `@{}` on the reference

```
foreach (@{$data->{array}}) { print "$_\n"; }
```

**Edit:**
Or if you dont want to use `{...}` after `@`

```
my $arrayref = $data->{array}; 

foreach (@$arrayref ) { print "$_\n"; }
```

Comment: Damned, I've tried `@[...]` and `@(...)` but not `@{...}`